# OS X Lion new Finder view that doesn't allow sorting

Tags: osx-lion, finder

In OS X, from Lion onwards, when I click on some of my folders in Finder and the title row of the files contains the usual stuff like "Date Modified" and "Size". However unlike the old Finder view I can't click on them to sort. Why is that and how do I make it never show up ever again?

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Make sure "None" is selected in the sorting options menu - else you have the behavior you described.

[image]

Comment: Found this confusing, too. "Arrange by" and "sort by" are almost synonymous -- it feels broken when they're actually mutually exclusive states.

Comment: It's awful. I created a new folder that was sortable just fine. I then created a subfolder that had this "feature".

Comment: Damn Apple. I write programs that can sort within grouping, why can't they?!? "It just works?" Hardly. Anyway, thanks @Vervious for the answer to my Apple-induced frustration for the day. +1

Answer (score 3):

Check out [In OS X Lion, Finder will not "Arrange..."](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3204144?start=0&tstart=0) from Apple Support Communities.

You'll find how to solve that problem:

> There seem to be a few glitches in the Arrange/sort model. You can
> actually Arrange by and Sort By separately. You can get to the Sort
> options by holding down the Option key while selecting the Arrangement
> button.
>
> However, there aren't any sort options when you Arrange by
> Name. And it doesn't change the sort by option when you switch to
> Arrange by Name.
>
> Try setting the Arrange by to None. Then, hold down
> the option key and press the Arrange button. What is it sorted by?